# Is there a foursquare api method for venues owners to post schedules to?

Tags: foursquare

Right now, when you check into a movie theater, you have the ability to check into a specific movie showing.

If you're a venue owner that has a schedule that people can check into, is there a foursquare api method that lets you upload your schedule?  What do the movie theaters use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This schedule you're referring too is called "events" on Foursquare.  Foursquare is currently partnered with ESPN (sporting events), MovieTickets.com (Movie Times) & SongKick (concerts) for the data you're seeing.  There is no way (currently) for you to create an event at a venue using the Foursquare api. However, it looks like this feature may be on its way based on the update at the end of this blog post.
http://blog.foursquare.com/2011/08/18/foursquare_events/

Answer (score 0):

Not through the API, the current ability to edit a venue in FourSquare can be found at: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/edit

Events can be viewed through a venue using the API here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events

Once you manage a venue on FourSquare, you can maintain it through the Dashboard - found here:
https://foursquare.com/business/merchants/dashboard